# Gtk-rs Error: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"

Tags: ubuntu, rust, gtk-rs

---

When I try to run my gtk-rs project it shows this error:
`Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"`

and also this error:
`Failed to register: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown`

My toml file looks like:

```
[package]
name = "something"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["gd"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
gtk = { git = "https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk.git" }
gio = { git = "https://github.com/gtk-rs/gio.git" }
```

I have tried re-installing appmenu-gtk3-module/appmenu-gtk2-module:

```sh
sudo apt reinstall appmenu-gtk3-module appmenu-gtk2-module
```

I use Pop-os (Ubuntu).

Comment: So, where is the question of your problem? Is it just information that you want to share?
Actually: **sudo apt reinstall appmenu-gtk3-module appmenu-gtk2-module** is the solution that also works for me.